# OpenTK and GPL license?

Tags: licensing, opentk

I want to open source my project and use a GPL license with OpenTK.

Can a GPL license be used with OpenTK?

Comment: Relevant: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204410/how-are-gpl-compatible-licenses-like-mit-usable-in-gpl-programs-without-being-su  OpenTK is MIT-License according to Google

Answer (score 0):

OpenTK is MIT licensed and includes additional 3rd party code from ILM (Industrial Light & Magic - Lucasfilm).

If it were my project, I would do a deep dive into the ILM code and make certain that you have full authorization to use it.
https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/master/THIRD_PARTIES.md

Generally speaking, a GPL Licensed Project can include MIT Licensed (ie, Public Domain) code.

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software

Combining Public Domain code (~80% of "OSI Approved Open Source" software) with GPL style Free-Software licensed code is fine, because you can do whatever you like with items in the public domain.

Good luck with your project!